# IndexRoute not being displayed inside a route

Tags: reactjs

I am a React novice and I have created a basic routing app that contains a route and an index route as a child. The routes.js file is the following:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;
var ApplicationHeader = require('../new_components/ApplicationHeader');
var MainPage = require('../new_components/MainPage');

var routes = (
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
<Route path="/" component={ApplicationHeader}>
  <IndexRoute component={MainPage}/>
</Route>
</Router>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

The ApplicationHeader.js file is the following:

```
var React = require('react');

var ApplicationHeader = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
      return (<header>
        <div>Application Header</div>
      </header>)
    }
  }
)

module.exports = ApplicationHeader;
```

The MainPage.js file is the following:

```
var React = require('react');

var MainPage = React.createClass({

  render: function(){
    return(<div>Main Page</div>);
  }
})

module.exports = MainPage;
```

When running the application however, only the 'Application Header' element is shown. I do expect that the main page element should be shown too, but it doesn't. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ApplicationHeader component you need to render the children as well

```
var React = require('react');

var ApplicationHeader = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
      return (
        <div>
           <header>
             <div>Application Header</div>
           </header>
           <div>{this.props.children}</div> 
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
)

module.exports = ApplicationHeader;
```